# Print variable line by line with string in front Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, line-by-line

I am writing a recon tool in Python and I've run into a bit of a problem trying to print a string in front of a multiple line variable without editing the string itself

Here is my sliver of code:

```
# ...
query1 = commands.getoutput("ls -1 modules/recon | grep '.*\.py$' | grep -v '__init__.py'")
print("module/%s/%s" % (module_type, query1.strip(".py"))
```

I want to add the "module/#module_type/#module_name" and the module name being the only changing thing. So, using the shodan and bing module (random) the output would look something like this:

```
modules/recon/shodan
modules/recon/bing
```

but instead I get

```
modules/recon/bing.py
shodan
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are asking for like this:

```
from os import path

module_type = 'recon'
q = 'shoban.py\nbing.py'  # insert the your shell invocation here
modules = (path.splitext(m)[0] for m in q.split('\n'))
formatted = ('modules/%s/%s' % (module_type, m) for m in modules)
print('\n'.join(formatted))
```

output:

```
modules/recon/shodan
modules/recon/bing
```

But since you are already calling a unix shell from python, you might as well use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) for string processing:

```
print(commands.getoutput("ls modules/recon/ | sed '/.py$/!d; /^__init__.py$/d; s/\.py$//; s/^/modules\/recon\//'"))
```

You can also use shell's "globbing" feature to make the command simpler if the location where you are looking for the modules (e.g modules/recon) matches the prefix you need to output:

```
print(commands.getoutput("ls modules/recon/*.py | sed 's/.py$//; /\/__init__$/d'"))
```

Another option is to use just python's standard library:

```
from os import path
import glob

module_type = 'recon'
module_paths = glob.iglob('modules/recon/*.py')
module_files = (m for m in map(path.basename, modules) if m != '__init___.py')
modules = (path.splitext(m)[0] for m in module_files)
formatted = ("modules/%s/%s" % (module_type, m) for m in modules)
print('\n'.join(formatted))
```

Comment: This is nitpicking but you can use `os.path.splitext` to get rid of the file extension instead of the literal `s[-3]`

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский it appears I accidentally unaccepted it. The code works well and I got it working. Thank you!